# find an object by key values 2 levels deep

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/y1tq9563/29/

In the below you can click on `shop-all` and `23` will be returned because 23 is the ID in the same obj as the the query, `shop-all`... BUT when the query is in a child node like `blade-servers`— id: 26 should return but it doesnt because `.find` is not looking in the `children` node.

**How do i rewrite**

```
data.find( t => t.url.includes(query).id
```

**so that it will also look in the `children` node of each?**

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Shop All",
    "url": "/shop-all/",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Servers",
    "url": "/Servers/",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "Blade Servers",
        "url": "/servers/blade-servers/"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "Rack Servers",
        "url": "/servers/rack-servers/"
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "Tower Servers",
        "url": "/servers/tower-servers/"
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Workstations",
        "url": "/servers/workstations/"
      }
    ]
  }
];

$('.btn').click(e=> getID($(e.target).html()) );

function getID(query){
    /* reset */
    $('.results').html('');
    $('.err').html('');
    
   /* search for "query" */
    try {
      const result = data.find( t => t.url.includes(query) ).id; // whats wrong here?
      $('.results').html(`<div class="res-c">${result}</div>`);
    } catch(er) {
        $('.err').html(`<div class="err-c">${er}</div>`)
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.res-c {
   color: #6CE891;
   padding: 0.5em;
   margin: 0.5em;
   border: 2px solid #6CE891;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
.err-c {
   color: #ff4f68;
   padding: 0.5em;
   margin: 0.5em;
   border: 2px solid #ff4f68;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.buttons{
  margin: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #20262e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons">
  <a class="btn">shop-all</a>
  <a class="btn">blade-servers</a>
</div>

<div class="results"></div>
<div class="err"></div>
```

> Maybe I need to map `.children:[i]` to the parent level?

Comment: Are there only two levels or could it be an arbitrarily deep tree?

Comment: an answer only 2 deep is what i need. but if it is not hard i would like to see 3 deep  too

Comment: Write a recursive function then, which works for any number of levels

Comment: To me this seems like a data modeling problem. Instead of storing the children within the parents, I'd probably store them all at the same level and have references to the parent instead, like the `parent_id`. That way you can search the array without worrying about depth. Of course, if there is some dependency on the nested structure that you haven't indicated, then this wouldn't be possible. From what you've shown though, seems like you could do that and it would simplify a lot. Wouldn't have to worry about recursion and still would have arbitrary depth.

Comment: I’m not in control of the data model. My is was to find a recursive find that’s reasonably timed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the *child* ID *or* the parent ID, you might use `reduce` to check the parent's ID and then `.find` a matching child, if any. A plain `.find` alone won't be enough here:

```
const result = data.reduce((a, { url, children, id }) => {
  if (a) return a;
  if (url.includes(query)) return id;
  const foundChild = children.find(({ url }) => url.includes(query));
  if (foundChild) return foundChild.id;
}, null);
```

If you add more levels later, better to use a recursive function instead.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "Shop All",
    "url": "/shop-all/",
    "children": []
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Servers",
    "url": "/Servers/",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 26,
        "name": "Blade Servers",
        "url": "/servers/blade-servers/"
      },
      {
        "id": 24,
        "name": "Rack Servers",
        "url": "/servers/rack-servers/"
      },
      {
        "id": 25,
        "name": "Tower Servers",
        "url": "/servers/tower-servers/"
      },
      {
        "id": 27,
        "name": "Workstations",
        "url": "/servers/workstations/"
      }
    ]
  }
];

$('.btn').click(e=> getID($(e.target).html()) );

function getID(query){
    /* reset */
    $('.results').html('');
    $('.err').html('');
    
   /* search for "query" */
    try {
      const result = data.reduce((a, { url, children, id }) => {
        if (a) return a;
        if (url.includes(query)) return id;
        const foundChild = children.find(({ url }) => url.includes(query));
        if (foundChild) return foundChild.id;
      }, null)
      $('.results').html(`<div class="res-c">${result}</div>`);
    } catch(er) {
        $('.err').html(`<div class="err-c">${er}</div>`)
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.res-c {
   color: #6CE891;
   padding: 0.5em;
   margin: 0.5em;
   border: 2px solid #6CE891;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
.err-c {
   color: #ff4f68;
   padding: 0.5em;
   margin: 0.5em;
   border: 2px solid #ff4f68;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

.buttons{
  margin: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #20262e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons">
  <a class="btn">shop-all</a>
  <a class="btn">blade-servers</a>
</div>

<div class="results"></div>
<div class="err"></div>
```

Comment: need child id not parent if applicable

Comment: This is great thank you... How much better does it get if i only go 2 deep?

Comment: @Omar The code above only goes 2 deep. For more, you'll have to write a recursive function.